# value error encountered when using sklearn for linear regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working with linear regression (SKlearn) and when predicting a value I am getting an error. I'm not sure what to do and have tried switching up the format in which I input the prediction value but so far I have drawn a blank.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

print(data.head())

X = data['Machine Age (Months)'].values
y = data['Mean Time Between Failure (Days)'].values

X.shape # (30,)
y.shape # (30,)

X = [X]
y = [y]

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X,y)
prediction = model.predict([[30]])
```

when running this code i get this error:

```
matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 30 is different from 1)
```

here's the data I'm importing (i made it a CSV file)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10fEjJj2znOmRufq3cFuc0CB_t2HAgudI/view?usp=sharing

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: remove this line: `y = [y]`

Comment: it just returned: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 30]`

Comment: im not sure if thats improvement

Comment: Make a print of `X.shape` and `y.shape` and see what you have.

Comment: sure ill add it to the question

Comment: It seems you create an empty array of size 30. You should write a test set with the same number of columns as X for prediction.

Comment: do you think passing X and y into numpy arrays and then reshaping them with (-1,1) would help?

Comment: Why? Your `fit` method works well. It is the prediction which gives the error. I answered, hoping it will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about your input for the prediction.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
X_test = np.array([[30]])
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```